# how to stop this jquery setInterval function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a timer function that, when it gets below 1 minute, calls this function to flash certain text. (based on this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8yned9f9/5/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                setInterval(function(){
                    $('.flash').toggleClass('active');
                }, 500);
            });
```

After the minute expires, I need to STOP toggling the class and leave it with .active turned off. I'm unsure how to do this.

Keep in mind that there is a js window.setInterval timer that must continue to run, only the jquery call should stop.

UPDATE

Based on some answers here I have added a variable so I can call clearInterval(flash)

```
flash = setInterval(function(){
                            $('.flash').toggleClass('active');
                        }, 500);
```

That works as far as stopping the interval from firing. But it stops in the wrong state. Is there a way to then remove the .active class after stopping the interval?

Update 2, solved removing the class with a quick search.

```
document.getElementById("seconds").classList.remove("active");
```

Comment: jQuery does not have a `setInterval` function. That is JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign your interval to a variable and use the variable to stop it with clearInterval

```
var variable = setInterval(examplefunction, 10000);

clearInterval(variable);
```

Edit:

To remove the class, you need to do this:

```
$("yourelement").removeClass( ".active" );
```

Comment: See update to question. This works but stops in the wrong state. I need to turn of .active after stopping the interval.

Comment: answered to your comment

Answer (score 1):

The `setInterval` function returns an **interval id** to be used in the case you want to stop the interval function. You can stop it by using the id as a parameter to the function `clearInterval`.

In your example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var intervalId = setInterval(function(){
        $('.flash').toggleClass('active');
    }, 500);
    // stop after 60 seconds
    setTimeOut(function() {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
    }, 60000)
});
```

The `setInterval` function belongs to the `window` object and is not related to jquery. You can find more information about `setInterval` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

Answer (score 0):

setInterval() returns an id. save this id somewhere in a global variable of some sort.

Let's say you saved it to a variable "interval". You can then stop the interval by calling `clearInterval(interval)`.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest would be to just add a condition in your script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var count = 1;
  setInterval(function () {
    if (count < 120) {
      $('.flash').toggleClass('active');
      count++;
    }
  }, 500);
});
```

However, it is unclear to me why you would want the setInterval to continue if it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

var variable = setInterval(examplefunction, 10000);

clearInterval(variable);

Answer (score 0):

You could set another timer to deal with it after one minute, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var id = setInterval(function(){
    $('.flash').toggleClass('active');
  }, 500);
  setTimeout(function () {
    clearInterval(id); // stop the setInterval
    $('.flash').addClass('active'); // make sure active is ON.
  }, 6000); // after 6 seconds (make this one minute if you want)
});
```

```css
.flash {color: red}
.flash.active {color: black}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flash">Hello</div>
```

For illustration purposes the flashing stops after 6 seconds. Adapt as needed.